# I am not able to print the array in form of table

Tags: java

I need to print a 2d array in the form of table.
I am getting the output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

...But I need it in the form of table like :

```
1 2 3    
4 5 6
```

```java
public static void main(String args[]){     
    int count=0;    

    rotateimage image=new rotateimage();    
    int[][] array=new int[5][5];    

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){    
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){    
            array[i][j]=count++;    
        }     
    }     

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){    
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){    
            System.out.println(array[i][j]+" ");    
        }    
        System.out.println();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this code should output a new line between 3 and 4?

Comment: for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)

Comment: Every value is on a new line because you call `println`. If you don't want to start a new line after the value, **use `print`**.

Comment: if you use `System.out.print()` it will keep printing on the same line otherwise if u use `System.out.println()` it will print on a new line.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are printing them on a new line everytime you loop by using "println" method. What you want to do is to use `System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");` because `println` moves to a *new line* and on the other hand `println()` continues on the same line.

which would give the following result:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24
```

```
public static void main(String args[]){    

    int count=0;    

    int[][] array=new int[5][5];    

    for(int i=0;i < array.length;i++) {    
        for(int j=0;j < array[i].length;j++) {    
            array[i][j]=count++;    
        }     
    }     

    for(int i=0;i < array.length;i++) {    
        for(int j=0;j < array[i].length;j++) {  

            // use print() instead of println()
            System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");    
        }    

        System.out.println();    
     }     
 }
```

Comment: Oh ya.got it..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in the second for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Just use print instead of prinln and it should be fixed.